# scraping a website to an array using table

Tags: php, html

can someone help please.

i want to scrape a website with a table in.

the table headers are

scheduled,
from,
flight,
status,
terminal,

i then want to output this to an array.

then i want to search the array outputting the data into text boxes.

can anyone help please.

Many thanks in advance

i have tried tried the below

```
<?php

$htmlContent = file_get_contents("http://www.gatwickairport.com/flights/");

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

$Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
$Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

//#Get header name of the table
foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
{
    $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}
//print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
{
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
}
//print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
    {
        $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
    }
}
$aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData; unset($aTempData);
print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();
?>
```

but i need it to only do columns 1,2,3,4,5 not 0,6,7,8,9

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try along these lines - where you determine the column indices of the ones you wish to keep and use `in_array` to test

```
$cols=array(1,2,3,4,5);
for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++){
        if( in_array( $j, $cols ) ) $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

---

To answer your subsequent question I hope the following might be of use to you. ( Try running it "as-is" to see the results )

```
$url='http://www.gatwickairport.com/flights/';
$html=file_get_contents( $url );


if( $html ){

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $html );
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );


    $headers=array();
    $data=array();
    $cols=array(1,2,3,4,5);


    /* Get column headers */
    $col=$xp->query( '//div[@class="container"]/table/thead/tr/th' );

    /* Get & store the number of column headers */
    $length=$col->length;

    /* Iterate through headers and store the ones you wish to keep */
    if( !empty( $col ) ){
        foreach( $col as $i => $node ) {
            /* array/collection is zero based so we need one more as the index */
            $j=$i+1;
            if( $node->tagName=='th' && in_array( $j, $cols ) ) $headers[]=trim( $node->nodeValue );
        }
    }

    /* Get row data */
    $col=$xp->query( '//div[@class="container"]/table/tbody/tr/td' );
    $rows=$col->length;

    /* each row will have $length columns, there will be $rows rows */
    $j=1;
    $r=1;

    if( !empty( $col ) ){
        foreach( $col as $i => $node ) {

            if( $node->tagName=='td' && in_array( $j, $cols ) ) {
                /* Because the airline column displays an image, treat it differently */
                if( $j==1 && $node->hasChildNodes() && $node->childNodes->item(0)->tagName=='img' ){
                    $value=$node->childNodes->item(0)->getAttribute('alt');
                } else {
                    /* standard cell content */
                    $value=trim( $node->nodeValue );
                }

                /* Add new row/cell data to output */
                $data[ 'row_'.$r ][]=$value;
            }

            if( $j >= $length ) {
                $j=0;
                $r++;
            }
            $j++;
        }
    }


    /* do stuff with the output data ( 2 arrays ) */
    echo '<pre>',print_r($headers,true),'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data,true),'</pre>'; 
}
```

Comment: For OP's particular use case, I would make the inner for loop `for (j=1; j < 6; j++)` so you can leave out the following `if` statement.  But I agree that an array with the column numbers would be good for an irregular set of columns ... (0, 3, 4, 5, 9) for example ... or when you might not know in advance which columns are needed.

Comment: would anyone be able to show me how to specify the <th> to choose from i again require it to be 1,2,3,4,5 not 0,6,7,8,9

Comment: you absolute legend, thank you so much RamRaider worked an absolutre charm.

Comment: this was fantastic but still being new to the scene. i cant for the life of me search this array to get a value. i want to search column 3 from each array and return column 1 & 4 in text boxes.